# Ant design form issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am trying to build a table that is editable using ant design. going through exactly by documentation of ant design, there occurs an error.
`Form.useForm()` is not a function

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { Table, Input, Button, Form } from "antd"

const EditableContext = React.createContext()

const EditableRow = ({ index, ...props }) => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm()
  return (
    <Form form={form} component={false}>
      <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
        <tr {...props} />
      </EditableContext.Provider>
    </Form>
  )
}

...
```

what I guess the problem is arising here:
`const [form] = Form.useForm()`

What might be the solution?
**N.B.** my ant design version is **'^3.26.12'**

Comment: Which version of ant design are you using?

Comment: I am using version ^3.26.12 @Agney

Comment: I am also having the same issue since 3 days

Comment: that's your problem right there, the docs you are reading are for v4. switch to using v3 docs or upgrade @Md.AbdulHalimRafi

Comment: Your wise advise helped me to sort out my issue..  If I use v4, what step should I take? @Agney

Comment: @ShawonChy I did not understand the question. If you use v4, you will not run into this error

Comment: Do I need to migrate to v4 first to use it ?

Comment: @ShawonChy yes, here is guide https://ant.design/components/form/v3. You can check my answer as well

Answer (score 3):

You are using AntD v3 and using the docs for v4. You should use the docs for v3 for this: https://3x.ant.design/docs/react/introduce

This is where you find info about the form: https://3x.ant.design/components/form/

https://ant.design/components/form/v3 - for migrating from v3 to v4 (if you want to use Form.useForm)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating you AntD version to v4.x or use documentation for [AntD v3.x](https://3x.ant.design/components/form/).  AntD v4.x uses `const [form] = Form.useForm()` whereas AntD v3.x uses `Form.create({ name: 'form-name' })` to create form. This is where you have to change.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade v3 to v4, and v4 form is beautiful
[image]